# Google Drive Python API Client insufficient permission for files().insert()

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This code (which is based on the quickstart.py example in https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python)...

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

media_body = MediaFileUpload('small_data_file.txt', mimetype='text/plain')
body = {'title': 'My document', 'description': 'A test document', 'mimeType': 'text/plain'}

file = service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
```

... gives me a HttpError 403 Insufficient Permission.

The scope is: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

Both files().list() and files.get() work fine.
MediaFileUpload is apiclient.http.MediaFileUpload()

Is there a problem with the scope or is the problem something completely different?

Comment: I tried the code and worked for me. Try creating new tokens and also try inserting a file in a different environment like in the "try it" section in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: "Creating new tokens" was basically the answer, but it took me a while to understand why.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the *drive-python-quickstart.json* file created by *quickstart.py* was out of date.  I deleted that file.  Once *quickstart.py* created a new one, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see in  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#auth

that you need one out of 4 scopes for insert() for that app. Whats the permissions you have for it?

Comment: I am using the most permissive scope, so I don't think that is the problem.  See original question.